# Django - How can i get this objects count based on this relationship

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two models which are `Influencer` and `InfluencerList`. My model relationships are:

`User` and `InfluencerList` have many-to-one relationship (one user can have many lists)

`Influencer` and `InfluencerList` have many-to-many relationship (one influencer can be in multiple lists or one list can contain multiple influencers)

I want to display logged in users each lists name and count (how many influencers are in it)
I managed to list users own lists but i couldn't figured out how to get counts of that list. I suppose it should be done by using lookup (association) table.

Here is my **model.py**:

```
class Influencer(models.Model):

    # fields are not included for clarity  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url

class InfluencerList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name:', max_length=20, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lists')
    influencers = models.ManyToManyField('Influencer', related_name='lists') 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # some method like getCount() would be nice here
```

**view.py**:

```
class InfluencerListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Influencer
    context_object_name = 'Influencers' 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        logged_in_user = self.request.user
        context['InfluencerLists'] = logged_in_user.lists.all();
        return context
```

I'm also not sure if i have to add a field like **count** to my InfluencerList model. It would be very nice if someone could explain why or why not i should do that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you looking for `logged_in_user.lists.count()`?

Comment: @PedramParsian No, i dont want to get the count of total lists, i want to get count of influencers in each of the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logged_in_user.lists.values(
    'name',
).annotate(
    influencers_count=Count('influencers'),
)
```

It should return a list of dicts with:

```
[{'name': 'InfluenceList1', 'influencers_count': 10}, {'name': 'InfluenceList2', 'influencers_count': 20}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your particular Model structure and relationships it is possible that One User can have Multiple Lists of Influencers. 
Because I am not sure what you want to achieve with the `objects count` I will just show you which are the methods able to access all counters...based on your sample code:

```py
    from django.db.models import Count


    class InfluencerListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
        model = Influencer
        context_object_name = 'influencers'  # recommended lowercase variables

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            logged_in_user = self.request.user
            first_list = logged_in_user.lists.first()
            first_list_influencers_count = first_list.influencers.count()
            influencers_list = Influencer.objects.filter(lists__owner=logged_in_user)
            influencers_count = Influencer.objects.filter(lists__owner=logged_in_user).count()
            influencers_nested = logged_in_user.lists.values('name').annotate(influencers_count=Count('influencers'))
            extra_context = {
                'influencer_lists': logged_in_user.lists.all(),
                'influencer_lists_counter': logged_in_user.lists.count(),
                'first_list': first_list,
                'first_list_influencers_count': first_list_influencers_count,
                'influencers_list': all_influencers_list,
                'influencers_count': all_influencers_count,
                'influencers_nested': influencers_nested
            }
            context.update(extra_context)
            return context
```

Note: If you only need the `Counter/quantity` it is better to use `.count()` if you also need the `list` then you can easily get the `.all() | .filter()` and get the counter from `len(queryset_list)` (.py files) OR `{% queryset_list| length %}` (html templates files).